# Is possible create certificate with IIS and import in Apache?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

I was researching a lot about this issue, and I have some doubts I'd like to know.

We have some sites in a hosting (Linktrust.com) that need to be SSL.

I made a thread with Linktrust but they lack on support.

I'm wondering if we should generate the CSR in our IIS local server, and then export it for LinkTrust.  That way, we control the CSR, and are not reliant on LinkTrust if we have to renew or change it, or if LinkTrust goes away.  The question is, can IIS export the completed SSL Certificate in a format that LinkTrust can import it?

If we can do that, would be compatible with Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in principal you could.
1. Create the CSR on IIS
2. Import on IIS when you get certificate
3. Export with private key
4. Import onto server where you want to use it.